# Please enable syntax highlighting on Mathematics SE

Tags: discussion, feature-request, formatting

Would it be possible to enable [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108) (colour) for code blocks on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com)?

For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/4751173), on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com):

[image: example syntax highlighting]

My motivation for asking this question is that I was disappointed to see that the Python code in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3524205/194826) was in black & white.

Comment: You mean like the highlight one uses on pdf text documents ?

Comment: @Isabella I mean for code blocks.

Comment: I suppose that some users around here (including me) are not really familiar with the way syntax highlighting works on Stack Exchange sites. It might be good to give some pointers to basic info - I was able to find some links in the [corresponding tag-info on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/syntax-highlighting/info).

Comment: If you're posting any substantial amount of code then your question is probably off-topic.

Comment: To help other confused readers: This image is an example of syntax highlighting https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/879dd25a27f775a1450b63b96460e52b92fff4a5/97eb3/img/syntax-highlighting.png

Comment: It would be helpful to have your thoughts on how *syntax highlighting* would contribute to the site.  I suspect the posts at Math.SE will mainly involve pseudo-code rather than compiler parseable code specific to a programming language, but I'll try to quantify this impression.

Comment: There are some instances where non-pseudocode code fits in on MSE, though, for example in [tag:computer-algebra-systems], [tag:computational-mathematics], [tag:gap], [tag:magma-cas], etc.

Comment: @hardmath I am just talking from my experience as a user. I was disappointed to see that the program in my post was in black and white [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3524205/194826).

Comment: @GéryOgam Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Nevertheless, the mathematics involved in numerical analysis do not mandate writing code - beyond maybe pseudocode, and that's already a stretch. This site is about mathematics. There may be *some* code sometimes, but it's not the purpose of Math.SE.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting former staff member [@Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273775/295232):

> We do not usually turn it on for sites that do not have a majority of posts with code in them (Lego, cooking, RPG are examples of such sites). Security tends to have more prose than code - hence, it isn't turned on.
>
> The reason for this is that turning it on means including more JavaScript and slows everything down - performance matters to us.

Now, one could argue that MathJax is already ~1 MB or so (if I interpreted my browser tools correctly), which makes the 573 kB of Highlight.js less of a problem. (Yes, your browser caches those files; it's not 1.5 MB per page visit. Still, if you're on a slow 2G/3G connection ...)

Comment: There's a cooking site with a lot of code?

Comment: Is this request under consideration? Has it been rejected?

Answer (score -7):

It may be true that code snippets appear in a minority of questions and responses, but when they do, they can be quite valuable (e.g., for simulations or in support of various theory). Syntax highlighting can make such snippets more accessible, even to those not intimately familiar with the languages. Math benefits from various forms of popular expression. One that enjoys arguably broader use than math notation is code.